# Disabling translation of specific elements

Tags: html, google-translate

I'm using Google website translator plugin to translate my site  (https://translate.google.com/manager/website/).

The problem is that with this plugin **everything** will be translated into language X, **including pickup location names**. Is there any way to disable translation of a specific element (a dropdown list in my case)?

The only solution I could think of is entering corrections on the page. But I have over 50 different pickup locations that change regularly and entering corrections for them into 2 different languages is not feasible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that question out! The class="notranslate" works well.